# Show button after function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a search function and a button. I only want the button to appear after the search successfully returns a result, how can I do so?

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" class="searchFeature" ng-model="selected" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && searchFunction()" uib-typeahead="value for value in themename | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:7" placeholder="Start your search here.">
  <button>DL</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
       $scope.searchFunction = function() {
          // searchLayer.clearLayers();
          for ( var i = 0; i < $scope.allTheme.length; i++) {
              if ($scope.selected == $scope.allTheme[i].THEMENAME)
              {
                  $scope.selectedTheme = $scope.allTheme[i].QUERYNAME;
                  apiURL = 'url';
                      $http.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
                        $scope.apiResult = response.data.SrchResults;
                        $scope.apiResult.splice(0,1);
                        for (var i= 0; i < $scope.apiResult.length; i++) {
                          if ($scope.apiResult[i].Type == "Point"){
                             $scope.dataLatLng.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                             $scope.Lat.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[0]);
                             $scope.Lng.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[1]);
                             L.marker([$scope.Lat[i], $scope.Lng[i]], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup($scope.apiResult[i].NAME).addTo(searchLayer);
                           }

                        }
                      })
              }

          }

       }
```

What I tried doing:

```
   <a ng-href="" ng-click="" ng-if="selectedTheme ==''" download>SHP</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some flag in your angular controller and set this flag into your search function if successful and then you can use

```
<button ng-if="flagOn">DL</button>
```

Comment: I tried ng-if = "example != ' ' ", where example is a $scope that will execute inside my search function, but it isn't working

Comment: can you share the scope controller here?

Comment: app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.isSearchSuccess = false;
     $scope.searchFunction = function() {
        //after your api call in response. have you tried to set the flag like this
        $scope.isSearchSuccess = true
    }
});

Comment: Ok, that was a really easy solution. Why didn't i thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-if="trunOn">Search</button>
```

Or

```
<button ng-show="trunOn">Search</button>
```

- Add **ng-if** in html button element and
- Add condition in that function after the search successfully returns a result.
- Example: `$scope.trunOn = true;`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using ng-show directive

```
<button ng-show="showButton">DL</button>
```

In the search fuction after getting executed set $scope.showButton variable to true.